# SQL QUERY UNION ALL with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query code which gives me result but I want to sum same row result. I couldn't do it, is there any way to make this?

```
SELECT cam_1, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y, SUM(adet_z) as adet_z, SUM(toplam_m2) as toplamm2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_1 Is Not NULL And cam_1 <> '' 
    GROUP BY cam_1, en_x, boy_y, cam1aciklama 

    union all 

    SELECT cam_2, cam2aciklama, en_x, boy_y, SUM(adet_z) as adet_z, SUM(toplam_m2) as toplamm2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_2 Is Not NULL And cam_2 <> '' 
    GROUP BY cam_2, en_x, boy_y, cam2aciklama 

    union all 

    SELECT cam_3, cam3aciklama, en_x, boy_y, SUM(adet_z) as adet_z, SUM(toplam_m2) as toplamm2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_3 Is Not NULL And cam_3 <> '' 
    GROUP BY cam_3, en_x, boy_y, cam3aciklama
    order by en_x desc
```

[image: my result]

For example, 1828 x 488 should be 2, not 1 twice.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the unions first then sum:

```
select cam_1 as cam, cam1aciklama as acıklama, en_x, boy_y, 
    sum(adet_z) as adet_z, sum(toplam_m2) as toplamm2
from
(SELECT cam_1, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_1 Is Not NULL And cam_1 <> '' 
    union all 
SELECT cam_2, cam2aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_2 Is Not NULL And cam_2 <> '' 
    union all 
    SELECT cam_3, cam3aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2 
    FROM siparis_detay 
    Where Siparis_no= '901405' and (STOKTIPI='1' or STOKTIPI='2') and cam_3 Is Not NULL And cam_3 <> '') tmp 
    GROUP BY cam_1, en_x, boy_y, cam1aciklama
    order by en_x desc;
```

Probably this could be written easier without unions and with a single query but we don't know the details and don't have sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
SELECT cam, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y,
       SUM(adet_z) as adet_z, SUM(toplam_m2) as toplamm2 
FROM ((SELECT cam_1 as cam, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2, Siparis_no, STOKTIPI
       FROM siparis_detay 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT cam_2, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2, Siparis_no, STOKTIPI
       FROM siparis_detay 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT cam_3, cam1aciklama, en_x, boy_y, adet_z, toplam_m2, Siparis_no, STOKTIPI
       FROM siparis_detay 
      ) 
     ) s
WHERE Siparis_no = '901405' AND
      STOKTIPI IN ('1', '2') AND
      cam <> ''   -- this eliminates `NULL` as well
GROUP BY cam, en_x, boy_y, cam1aciklama ;
```

Note:  If `Siparis_no` or `STOKTIPI` are numbers, then the comparison values should not use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your fast solution but it didn't work just because of `Siparis_no` and `STOKTIPI`. It gives error: Invalid column name `STOKTIPI`. and `Siparis_no`. They are numbers. I tried them without quotes but didn't work. Should I try with double quote or something?

Comment: @TuğhanAvcı, Double quotes are for identifiers. Be sure you have such columns.

Comment: Ok when I add `STOKTIPI` and `Siparis_no` to select queries it worked. Thank you very much @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION instead of UNION ALL. If we use UNION we will end up getting only distinct data.

Comment: But that could lead to wrong result. Here UNION ALL is the correct choice.